# input type file not workin Bulma.io

Tags: html, css, input, bulma

I'm using Bulma.io CSS Framework, and i had an issue while using the **input type File**, No CSS is applyied to it, but the rest of the form is working fine, all other Inputs are getting the styles !
**My web page, as you can see ! other styles working except for input type file**
[image: My webpage]

> Here my source code : https://pastebin.com/ZnQxSJpz

```
                                <div class="file">
                                <label class="file-label">
                                    <input class="file-input" type="file" name="image">
                                    <span class="file-cta">
                                        <span class="file-icon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="file-label">
                                            Max: 5Mo
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="file-name">

                                    </span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
```

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

File inputs were added in the (at the time) latest experimental version 0.5.1

Try running `npm install bulma@latest` on your project

Comment: Not working, this they have issues with it, since i even created a new project and used the CDN, same problem no inputs style, anyway thank you for your answer ;)